# URL/address bar code to hide a specific div on the webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

It is possible to put some code on a link that when somebody press on the link to send a command to the browser in order to hide a specific div in the link target webpage? Thank you.

Comment: yes it's possible but did you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your goal is to have a div hide when the user clicks a link, there's no need to reload the whole page with some fancy querystring. Just call a javascript function when the link is clicked:

```
<div id='hide-me'>This is the div you want to hide</div>    
<a href='#' onclick='hideTheDiv()'>hide something</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function hideTheDiv() {
        $('#hide-me').hide();
    }
</script>
```

For your info, the `href='#'` tells HTML not to reload the page or go anywhere. so the page stays where it is. onclick tells HTML to run a javascript function.

Sounds like you've got some learning to do. checkout these resources:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp (can be applied to an anchor tag too, not just buttons)
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Thank you Chris, will follow

Comment: @Costi typically, stack overflow is not meant to ask "where do I start?", it's meant to ask "here's what I've tried, what am I doing wrong?". In the future, make an effort to try something first, and post your attempt as part of the question.